# Extract subset of string in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Ruby application, I have a file upload that I've set up with AWS. When displaying uploaded files back to the user, I would like to display only the name of the uploaded file, not the entire file.

In my view, I'm using:

```
<td>
    <%= link_to file.file_url.split('/').last, file.file_url, target: '_blank' %>
</td>
```

Which outputs something like `File_name.pdf` instead of `https://bucket_name.s3-us-west.../file_name.pdf`, which is exactly what I need.

However, for certain file uploads, there are parameters appended to the file name, so I get something like `File_name.pdf?AWSAccessKeyID=1234&Expires=1234`. When displayed in a view, that looks ugly as hell.

I would like to split file URL string at the last trailing slash, and then again at the "?". I've tried `slash` and `chomp` but can't seem to format it correctly. Is that the appropriate approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably create a helper which will take `file.file_url` and convert it to "File_name.pdf", it will look like this:

```
def aws_file_name(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url) # =>  #<URI::HTTPS https://bucket_name.s3-us-west/.../File_name.pdf?AWSAccessKeyID=1234&Expires=1234>
  File.basename(uri.path) # => "File_name.pdf"
end
```

Then:

```
<%= link_to aws_file_name(file.file_url), file.file_url, target: '_blank' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`new_str = str.slice(0..(str.index('?')))` will cut the filename after the first occurence of `?`
where `str` is your current filename and `new_str` will be the cut version.

//edit
`new_str` will still contain the `?`
if you don't want this to happen then try using `new_str = str.split('?')[0]`